# Has the pear shape of the earth been measured?

Tags: geodesy

I have heard Neil degrasse Tyson say the earth is pear shaped but I can’t find any source for this.

We all know the earth has an equatorial bulge because it spins but Neil says “it’s slightly wider below the equator than above it”

I’d just like someone to explain why this is and if there is any source that has measured this.

Comment: https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/earth-is-not-round/ and https://oceanservice.noaa.gov/facts/earth-round.html have some explanations about what causes changes in shape. Pear-shaped sounds extreme... but it's only 20 meters.  I think potato-shaped is a better description.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Figure_of_the_Earth